# javascript remove an item from an array stored in the local Storage

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input field that add task. when i add the task a delete button appear next to each task
these task are stored in the local storage as an array
when i click delete button i want to delete the specific item not all the local storage

in general we use `localStorage.removeItem(key);`

```js
let inputTask = document.querySelector('.input');
let tasks = document.querySelector('.tasks');
let add = document.querySelector('.add');
let alls = [];

//show tasks
function show() {
    if (window.localStorage.task) {
        let storedTaskes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("task"));
        storedTaskes.forEach((item) => {
            let paragraph = document.createElement('p');
            let deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
            deleteBtn.className = "delete";
            deleteBtn.innerHTML = "Delete";
            deleteBtn.id = item;
            deleteBtn.setAttribute("onclick","deleteBtn(this)");
            console.log(deleteBtn.value);
            paragraph.innerHTML = item;
            paragraph.appendChild(deleteBtn);
            tasks.appendChild(paragraph);
        });
    }
}

// add tasks
add.onclick = function () {
    if (inputTask.value.trim() !== "") {
        alls.push(inputTask.value);
        for (let i = 0; i < alls.length; i++) {
            window.localStorage.setItem(`task`, JSON.stringify(alls));
        }
    }
    inputTask.value = '';
    show();
}

show();

//Delete Task
function deleteBtn(ob) {
    let id = ob.id;
    let taskArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("task"));
    for(let i = 0; i < taskArray.length; i++){
        if(taskArray[i] === id){
            localStorage.removeItem(taskArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
}

.form {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-item: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 15px;
}

.input{
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.add,
.delete{
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tasks {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 500px;
}

p {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;

}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="form">
            <input type="text" class="input">
            <input type="submit" class="add" value="Add Task">
        </div>
        <div class="tasks"></div>
    </div>
```

How can i delete the specific item from the array in the local storage and show the new result for the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove from the array and store the array again since that is how your other part works

```js
function deleteBtn(ob) {
  let id = ob.id;
  let taskArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("task"));
  taskArray = taskArray.filter(item => item != id)
  localStorage.setItem("task", JSON.stringify(taskArray));
  show()
}
```

ALso change

```
for (let i = 0; i < alls.length; i++) {
  window.localStorage.setItem(`task`, JSON.stringify(alls));
}
```

to

```
localStorage.setItem(`task`, JSON.stringify(alls));
```

Here is a better version

I use delegation for the delete and save to localstorage without reading it again

I use a generated ID as id

Note I have to comment out the localstorage part since SO does not allow it

```js
let inputTask = document.querySelector('.input');
let tasks = document.querySelector('.tasks');
let add = document.querySelector('.add');
let storedTasks // = localStorage.getItem("task"); // uncomment on your server
let allTasks = storedTasks ? JSON.parse(storedTasks) : [];

function show() {
  tasks.innerHTML = allTasks
    .map(task => `<p>${task.input} <button class="delete" data-id="${task.id}">X</button></p>`)
    .join('<br/>');
}

// add tasks
add.onclick = function() {
  const input = inputTask.value.trim();
  if (input !== "") {
    const id = allTasks.length; // use the length at this time
    allTasks.push({ id:new Date().getTime(), input });
  // localStorage.setItem("task",JSON.stringify(allTasks)); // uncomment on your server    
    inputTask.value = '';
    show();
  }
};

show();

document.querySelector(".tasks").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("delete")) {
    let id = tgt.dataset.id;
    allTasks = allTasks.filter(item => item.id != id)
    tgt.closest("p").remove();
    // localStorage.setItem("task",JSON.stringify(allTasks)); // uncomment on your server
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
}

.form {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-item: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 15px;
}

.input {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.add,
.delete {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tasks {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 500px;
}

p {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="form">
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <input type="submit" class="add" value="Add Task">
  </div>
  <div class="tasks"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you a lot. How can i show the new result without refreshing the page because when i add or delete appear the old and the new when i refresh the new result appear normaly

Comment: Empty document.querySelector('.tasks') in show

Comment: See updated  - you also need to change the way to save the task when adding

Comment: thank you a lot there is somthing one i add a new task and exist a task before the older task appear twice then the seconde one but one i refresh only the new results appear without duplication

Comment: I made you a new version that works better. You cannot have the same task twice with my code. If you need that we need to change things

Comment: yes i need to have the same task twice or maybe more

Comment: See update - I store with a generated ID and not the input text as an ID

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteBtn({id}) {
  let taskArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("task")); // get the array

  taskArray = taskArray.filter(ob=> ob.id != id )  // remove the id 

  localStorage.setItem("task", JSON.stringify(taskArray));

  show()
}
```

but since you are using `tasks.appendChild(paragraph)`
you will have to change `show` function to

```
//show tasks
function show() {
    if (window.localStorage.task) {
        let storedTaskes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("task"));
        tasks.innerHTML = "" // here
        storedTaskes.forEach((item) => {
            let paragraph = document.createElement('p');
            let deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
            deleteBtn.className = "delete";
            deleteBtn.innerHTML = "Delete";
            deleteBtn.id = item;
            deleteBtn.setAttribute("onclick","deleteBtn(this)");
            console.log(deleteBtn.value);
            paragraph.innerHTML = item;
            paragraph.appendChild(deleteBtn);
            tasks.appendChild(paragraph)
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `html += paragraph` will not work. It will show a lot of `[object HTMLElement]`

Comment: @mplungjan edited my answer, if you wish to use your old function, you just empty the tasks html tag first then append everything you need

Comment: Yeah: `Empty document.querySelector('.tasks') in show – 
mplungjan
 57 mins ago `  ;)))